# PL/pgSQL To Remap Values on Certain Matching Condition

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am looking to remap values on a column ('name' in this case) based on other column ('division'). Assume original data as below.

```
Name, Division
John, A
James, B
Mona, B
Derek, C
Lisa, C
```

If division is A or C, then name will be remapped to `(division) name`.
Thus, then end results required is:

```
Name, Division
(A) John, A
James, B
Mona, B
(C) Derek, C
(C) Lisa, C
```

I'm imagining the usage will be:

```
select remap_name(name), division from division_table;
```

I'd love to try myself first, but plpgsql is too new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just using `case`?

```
select (case when division in ('A', 'C') then '(' || division || ') ' || name
             else name
        end) as name
```

Comment: actually yes, that's pretty much what I need. thanks